# Existing implementation of Btree or B+tree in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, b-tree

I am doing a project in which I require btree or b+tree data structure. Does anyone know of an existing implementation of btree or b+tree (with insert, delete, search algorithms)? It should accept string as input and form btree or b+tree of these string.

Comment: @rohit: I have done some editing of your question to make it a less obvious candidate for "close as not a real question". If you do not like my changes, feel free to revert them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're going to be using the data structure for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the lack of details about the problem that you need to solve, I am going to allow myself to suggest an alternative solution that *might* solve your problem: use a red/black tree instead.

The red/black tree can be thought of as a b-tree, as explained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree#Analogy_to_B-trees_of_order_4):

> A red-black tree is similar in structure to a B-tree of order 4, where each node can contain between 1 to 3 values and (accordingly) between 2 to 4 child pointers. In such B-tree, each node will contain only one value matching the value in a black node of the red-black tree, with an optional value before and/or after it in the same node, both matching an equivalent red node of the red-black tree [...]

Java has two built-in classes, [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), providing red/black trees. None of these will take a string as input and grow a tree from it, but you might be able to implement something similar "around" one of those classes.

Answer (score 14):

[jdbm](http://jdbm.sourceforge.net/) has a very solid implementation of b+tree.  Also h+tree which is an interesting related data structure.

Comment: Since then there has been [JDBM3](https://github.com/jankotek/JDBM3) and [JDBM4 which was renamed to MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/).

Comment: @PeterLamberg yes - MapDB is shaping up to be a very nice project. Still a few weeks from first stable release, but it looks very good. Note that MapDB isn't using b+tree b/c of concurrency requirements - I believe they are using a linked tree of some sort.

Comment: Here is my disk-based B+-tree implementation.
https://github.com/myui/btree4j/

Answer (score 6):

I've had to implement my own and open sourced the [code](http://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/BTree.java).

Comment: Haven't tested it but the split method was what I was looking for with every insert and remove.  With only 2 elements this will occur almost all the time. 

Question: Do you shuffle the top level element? Say you have data from 1 -5000 (5000 for the sake of this comment) and you had the first element as 300, wouldn't it make sense to have that as closer to 2500?

Comment: btw.. +1 for your answer.

Comment: @TejaswiRana I've tested with 5000 elements (1-5000) and the root ended up with the 2048 value. The default implementation is 2-3 tree but that was just for testing purposes. You can pass in the order (minKeySize) of the tree in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Electric's [BTree](http://megacz.com/software/btree-javadoc/com/sun/electric/database/geometry/btree/BTree.html) ([author page here](http://megacz.com/software/btree.html)).