# What is an efficient and elegant way to add a single element to an immutable set?

Tags: java, guava

I have an immutable set (cast as a `Set<Integer>`) that potentially contains many elements. I need a Collection that contains the elements from that set plus one additional element. I have kludgy code in place to copy the set, then append the element, but I'm looking for The Right Way that keeps things as efficient as possible.

I have Guava available, though I do not require its use.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Not sure about performance, but you can use Guava's [`ImmutableSet.Builder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.Builder.html):

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet

// ...
Set<Integer> newSet = new ImmutableSet.Builder<Integer>()
                                .addAll(oldSet)
                                .add(3)
                                .build();
```

Of course you can also write yourself a helper method for that:

```
public static <T> Set<T> setWith(Set<T> old, T item) {
  return new ImmutableSet.Builder<T>().addAll(old).add(item).build();
}

// ...
Set<Integer> newSet = setWith(oldSet, 3);
```

Answer (score 22):

Using Java 8 you can also use streams for that effect

```
Stream.concat(oldSet.stream(),
              Stream.of(singleElement))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

By the way since JDK 10, the `Collectors` also allow to accumulate to immutable types (the same as the ones created by the static factories like `Set.of()`) :

```
Stream.concat(oldSet.stream(),
              Stream.of(singleElement))
      .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet())
```

Answer (score 8):

You might consider Sets.union().  Construction would be faster, but use slower.

```
public static <T> Set<T> setWith(Set<T> old, T item) {
  return Sets.union(old, Collections.singleton(item);
}
```

(com.google.common.collect.Sets & java.util.Collections)

Answer (score 3):

You have three options.

- Use a mutable set.
- Check the element isn't already present, if not create a copy of the set and add an element.
- Create a wrapper set which includes the previous set and the element.

Sometimes a `BitSet` is a better choice than `Set<Integer>` depending on the distribution of your values.

Comment: Can't use a mutable set - I do not control the API that returns the value. Checking that's it's not present is certainly good advice. Thanks.

Comment: The check is quick compared with the cost of the copy.

Comment: Wouldn't the builder do the check whether it is already present by itself? I mean before allocating a copy.

Answer (score 2):

If the Set is immutable, I don't see any way to do it other than copy the Set, and then add your new element.  Remember, copying a set is as easy as passing the base set to the constructor function when creating the new set.

Comment: I think this is implied; the question is about _how_ to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

When you want better performance than a full copy, and you have an ordering over elements, you can use an effectively immutable wrapper around a [B+ tree](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/14_2_B_Trees.html) to get good incremental set performance.

Adding an item to a B+ tree requires O(log(n)) time and incremental allocation, not O(n) as you get with `ImmutableSet.builder().addAll(...).add(...).build()`.  This means that building a set from n incremental adds is O(n*log(n)), not O(sqr(n)).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577029/20394) has a pointer to a jdbm library so it might be worth looking at [`jdbm:jdbm`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjdbm%7Cjdbm%7C1.0%7Cjar).

Answer (score -3):

I'm experiencing cognitive dissonance when I read "immutable" and "add to" in the same sentence.  You can add a new element to the end of a mutable copy of the immutable values, but you can't modify the immutable set.  I don't know of anything elegant.

Comment: There is no contradiction here. The number 3 is immutable, but you can still talk about adding 2 to 3 to return 5.

Comment: You do not understand what is happening.  If you add a new element to an immutable set you have not altered it one bit. You’ve created a new set that is a copy of the original immutable one with the new element added

Comment: Thanks, but that is exactly my understanding. Your answer here suggests that you did not understand that, but perhaps it is just poorly explained instead.

Comment: My point is that the word "add to" does not imply mutation; I had hoped to clarify this by analogy with adding integers. There was no need for you to incorrectly tell me what I do not understand; that was rude.